# jQuery On-click event not working as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I'm working on a project that returns GIFs from the GIPHY API, and whenever a search is executed, I'm capturing each search history item as its own button that a user can click on and see the results of the search as opposed to retyping the search again. I successfully added the buttons to the HTML with the proper classes, however, when I tried to write a simple on click event such as `$('.history-btn').on('click', function() {
    console.log('hello');
});`
nothing appears. What is causing this? Here is my whole set of code for context:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    

var searches = [];

function addSearch() {
    $(".prev-searches").empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < searches.length; i++) {
        var history = $('<button>');
        history.addClass("btn btn-primary history-btn");
        history.attr("data-name", searches[i]);
        history.text(searches[i]);
        $(".prev-searches").append(history);
    }
}


$('.history-btn').on('click', function() {
    console.log('hello');
});


function returnSearch() {
    var gifSearch = $(".search-input").val().trim();
    var queryURL = 'https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=XXXXX-HIDDEN-XXXXX&q=' + gifSearch + '&limit=15&offset=0&rating=PG&lang=en';
$.ajax({
    url: queryURL,
    method: "GET"
}).then(function(response){
    console.log(queryURL);
    console.log(response);
    console.log(response.data.length);
    for (var i =0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
        arrImg = response.data[i].images.fixed_width.url;
        var newContent = '';
        newContent = '<img src="' + arrImg + '">';
        $('.gif-area').html(newContent);
        console.log(newContent);
    }
});
}

//When search is executed
$('.search-btn').on('click', function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var search = $('.search-input').val().trim();
    searches.push(search);
    addSearch();
    returnSearch();
});


function renderGIFs () {
    for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
    var newGifs = '';
    newGifs += '<img src="' + response.data[i].bitly_gif_url + '"';
    $(".gif-area").html(newGifs);
    }
}

});
```

Comment: Your JavaScript can't find your HTML element with a class of `history-btn`. Please provide the relevant HTML as well (to confirm your selector targets); it's rather difficult to answer this question without it. It would help if you could update your question to list all **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need event delegation:**

```
$('.prev-searches').on('click', '.history-btn', function() {
    console.log('hello');
});
```

## Resource

- [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 0):

Is the class 'history-btn' added dynamically from your addSearch function?
Then please use an element which is above in heirarchy of history-btn and bind the event to that element.

For example I bind the event to the div element,

```
<div id='historybtncontainer'>
    <button class='history-btn'>Button</button>
</div>
```

and in script you can do

```
$('historybtncontainer').on('click', 'history-btn', function(){
    console.log("hello");
});
```

Comment: You forgot the `#` in your jQuery selector

Answer (score 0):

`document` allows you to get a new tree of elements after dynamically adding the `history-btn` class to the `<button>`

```
$(document).on('click', '.history-btn', function() {
console.log('hello');
});
```

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.